# Declaring memory on stack overwrites previously declared memory

Tags: c, stack, alloca

How can I allocate memory on the stack and have it point to different memory addresses so I can use it later? For example. this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int nums[5];
    nums[0] = 1;
    printf("%p\n", &nums[0]);
}
```

Will print out the same address every time. How can I write memory to stack (not the heap, no malloc) and have it not overwrite something else that's on the stack already.

Comment: Allocate a 5×5 array outside the loop?

Comment: Please can you explain better what you want ? We try to understand you but not sure we success ... and not sure you request something possible ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `alloca` to allocate a different array from the runtime stack for each iteration in the loop. The array contents will remain valid until you exit the function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void function() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int *nums = alloca(5 * sizeof(*nums));
        nums[0] = 1;
        printf("%p\n", (void *)nums);
        /* store the value of `num` so the array can be used elsewhere.
         * the arrays must only be used before `function` returns to its caller.
         */
        ...
    }
    /* no need to free the arrays */
}
```

Note however that `alloca()` is not part of the C Standard and might not be available on all architectures. There are further restrictions on how it can be used, see the documentation for your system.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for:

> a way to control how memory is being allocated on the stack, at least in the context of not overwriting already-used memory

Of course, that's taken care by the OS! The low level system calls will make sure that a newly created automatic variable will not be written upon an already used memory block.

In your example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  int nums[5];
  ...
}
```

this is *not* the case, since `nums` will go **out of scope**, when the i-th iteration of the for loop terminates.

As a result, the memory block `nums` was stored into during the first iteration, will be marked as free when the second iteration initiates, which means that when `nums` of the first iteration is going to be allocated in the stack, it will not be aware of any existence of the `nums` of the first iteration, since that has gone already out of scope - it doesn't exist!